Unexpected LOB_COMPACTION on DATETIME Column with Ola Hallengren's IndexOptimize
I'm using Ola Hallengren's IndexOptimize script for index maintenance on my SQL Server databases. We have a Clustered and 3 non-clustered indexes on a big table having rows over 685 million.
Reorganize was running more than 7 hours till morning on a non-clustered index with option LOB_COMPACTION = ON until it's killed explicitly. This index has only one key column on DATETIME type and no covering columns in there.
There is one column with type geography on this table but this column is not part of that index.
According to my understanding, LOB_COMPACTION should not be applicable to the index since DATETIME is not a LOB data type.
I'm expecting when REORGANIZE run on this non-clurtered index, it should run without LOB_COMPACTION = ON.
Here is the script I'm running in my SQL Agent job:
EXECUTE dbo.IndexOptimize @Databases = 'Database1,Database2',
                          @LogToTable = 'Y',
                          @FragmentationMedium = 'INDEX_REORGANIZE,INDEX_REBUILD_ONLINE',
                          @FragmentationHigh = 'INDEX_REBUILD_ONLINE',
                          @FragmentationLevel1 = 15,
                          @FragmentationLevel2 = 50,
                          @FillFactor = 90,
                          @Indexes = 'ALL_INDEXES',
                          @SortInTempdb = 'Y',
                          @MaxNumberOfPages = 10000000,
                          @Execute = 'Y';

We did not specify the @LOBCompaction parameter, so it defaults to 'Y'.
Has anyone else encountered this issue? Is there a known problem with the script, or am I missing something in my configuration?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!


Has anyone else encountered this issue? Is there a known problem with
the script, or am I missing something in my configuration?

There is no issue at all.
ALTER INDEX REORGANIZE

compacts (deallocates) empty LOB pages by default, so even if you don't specify LOB_COMPACTION at all, it's still there, but obviously, there is no compaction if there is no LOB pages.
This is online operation that is fully logged, the amount of log generated for big highly fragmented tables is enormous, in fact it's recommended to do index REBUILD if the fragmentation exceeds 30%
Where do the Books Online index fragmentation thresholds come from
Your table is a big one, your fragmentation could be even 49% (your parameters tell the sp to rebuild if fragmentation exceeds 50%) and the time you mentioned could be the effective time for your table.
For example, I have a table with 165 mlns of records, it's partitioned into 7 parts and offline index rebuild (the fastest one) of one partition takes up to 20 minutes,
so for the whole table the duration is over two hours but, index rebuild generates less log records compared to reorganize in case of heavy fragmentation.
You should monitor wait types in sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks while reorganizing your index to make an idea where the time is spent but I guess it will be WRITELOG
